# Adding a JLabel to a Panel - how to layout the components properly?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

I want to put some words in the frame so I used `panel1.add(new JLabel("Hello"));`

But there are some buttons which their sizes and positions are customized. I heard that we have to `setLayout(null)` for the button customizing and this is also making the label not showing up. (Not sure if it is because of this)

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Draw a rough sketch of your View on a `paper` or `Paint or some another Application`, paste the image here, so that one can guide you in the best way. You calling `setLayout(null)` for which thing. It can be the case that you forgot to specify the position for the `JPanel`, on which the `JLabel` is present. Though as said before, using **Absolute Positioning** is really not a good option to get things moving.

Answer (score 6):

I'll point you to the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for laying out components - they give a good introduction to Swing formatting and layouts.

Rather than calling `setLayout(null)`, you should probably call a specific `LayoutManager`, such as `setLayout(new FlowLayout());` so that Java knows how to display your components. You should call this before you try to add the components to the `JPanel`. The type of `LayoutManager` you give to the `setLayout()` method will instruct Java to draw the GUI in a specific way, such as in a Grid, or just one-after-the-other. The tutorial linked above will explain all this, and has a visual example of the different `LayoutManager`s

Answer (score 4):

Don't use null layout. Define rules how the buttons should be placed and either use some LayoutManager or create your own.