# how to keep GUIs from overlapping in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am trying to create a Java 7 address book using Eclipse and when I test run the JFrame, JLabels aren't visible and JButtons overlap. (Buttons will take up the whole JFrame)
For example

```
add(saveButton);
add(cancelButton);

add(headingLabel);

headingLabel.setVisible(true);

cancelButton.setLocation(200,200);
saveButton.setLocation(400,200);

cancelButton.setSize(200,50);
saveButton.setSize(200,50);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We need to see more code, what is your layout style? How is the JFrame defined?

Comment: Solution: learn about and use the layout managers. Don't use absolute positioning. This has been asked and answered **many** times on this site, and the answer does not vary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a JLabel to a Panel - how to layout the components properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605497/adding-a-jlabel-to-a-panel-how-to-layout-the-components-properly)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a LayoutManager instead of absolute coordinates. Using Layout managers, you don't have to care so much about the exact positions of your GUI elements. The layout is done for you.

Check out the [Visual Guide to Layout Managers.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) It explains the most common layout types with visual and code examples.